# Redis: atomic get if key exists?

Tags: redis

How can you check if a key exists and get its value if it does?

I am concerned with concurrency problems. Fox example

```
EXISTS foo
```

followed by

```
GET foo
```

There will be a problem if the key is deleted between `EXISTS` and `GET`. How should you deal with this?

Comment: Just `GET` it. You'll receive `nil` if it doesn't exist.

Comment: My bad. I though I was getting an error from hiredis instead of `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only GET method is sufficient in your use case.  Doing a GET on any key returns the Value of that key if the key is set, otherwise it simply returns a `(nil)`.